# normalize mat file in matlab

Tags: matlab, normalization

I have a mat file with a structure that looks like this:

[image]

How do I normalize the data and save it as a .dat file (ascii)

Comment: what do you mean by "normalize"?

Comment: 1) find the minimum and maximum dataset 2) find Normalized scale minimum and maximum 3) change all numbers in the data set to 4) Normalized value

Comment: I mean I can manually copy the data from the vec in the mat file and paste into excel then save as csv then convert the csv to .dat but there must be a way to save directly as .dat -ASCII

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you want to normalize each column.

There are two ways you can normalize:

(1) Set minimum to 0 and maximum to 1

```
dataset = bsxfun(@minus,dataset,min(dataset));
dataset = bsxfun(@rdivide,dataset,max(dataset));
```

(2) Set average to zero, standard deviation to 1 (if you don't have the Statistics Toolbox, use `mean` and `std` to subtract and divide, respectively, as above).

```
dataset = zscore(dataset);
```

**EDIT**

*Why anyone ever use option 2 to normalize?*

When you calculate the difference (dissimilarity) between different data points, you may want to weigh the different dimensions equally. Since dimensions with large variance will dominate the dissimilarity measure, you normalize the variance to one.

Comment: why not just vec = randn(494021, 42);?

Comment: @Garrith Graham: Because there may be correlation in your data.

Comment: using your method is there a way to specify the size to take from the dataset you will notice with mine I use vec = randn(494021, 42); I can change this to take only 10 or 1000 records from n columns

Comment: @GarrithGraham: Sure. Create a subset of your data as `subset = dataset(1:howeverManyRowsYouWant,:)`, then run my code with `subset` instead of `dataset`.

Comment: that doesnt work? its just outputs the subset with the same as the M file

Comment: @GarrithGraham: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, then.

Answer (score 0):

Your normalization:

```
dataset = dataset-ones(size(dataset,1),1)*min(dataset) % subtract min
dataset = dataset ./ (ones(size(dataset,1),1)*max(dataset)+eps) % divide by max
```